# enum does not name a type

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class `Response` say.

```
#include "NetworkResponse.h"


class NetworkResponse;

class Response {
public:
    Response();
    virtual ~Response();
    Response(NetworkResponse * networkResponse);

    NetworkResponses responseCode; // This is an enum and here I get an error


};

#endif
```

`NetworkResponses` is actually an enum defined in the `"NetworkResponse.h"`. Like this:

```
// "NetworkResponse.h":
#include "Response.h"

enum NetworkResponses {
    Success = 1,
    UserAlreadyExists = 2,
    InvalidUsername = 3,
        SecurityError = 4,
        UnknownError = 5

};
class Response;


class NetworkResponse {

public:
    NetworkResponse();
    virtual ~NetworkResponse();

};
```

But I get an error: : "*NetworkResponses* does not name a type" in the `Response` class definition, when I try to compile. Can someone please help?? I think I am missing something simple. I think I was able to use this enum in other classes successfully, don't know what's wrong in this case... Thanks.

Comment: is it within the same namespace?

Comment: The only this I see, but which shouldn't cause any problem, is the semicolon after the second `#include`. Is it possible for you to create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that have this problem and show us that?

Comment: One more thing here, is your enum and class declared in your header file in exactly the same order as you showed us here?

Comment: In your first snippet, you `#include "Response.h";`, which has a semicolon at the end and would cause an endless include recursion. Please show real code, otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: @RedSerpent yes same order, and btw. I don't use any namespaces

Comment: @ JoachimPileborg, @ OlafDietsche: I added some lines, but this looks very similar to what I have, I just have removed some lines since I thought they were not relevant for this problem (also to improve readability). I will see if I can add smth more..

Comment: Cyclic include dependency. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a cyclic include dependency: `NetworkResponse.h` includes `Response.h` and vice versa. This cannot work. `NetworkResponse.h` does not need to include `Response.h` at all, so you can remove that include.

Comment: Yes, but I am actually using a Response object in the NetworkResponse class too, e.g., 
 void (**callBack)(void* pt2Object, Response* genericResponse);
so, if I remove #include "Response.h" from here it won't compile??? Thanks,

Comment: @user2054339 Then _declare_ the `Response` class, just like you declare the `NetworkResponse` class in the response header file.

Comment: @user2054339 yes, but you are also including `Response.h`. I told you not to do that :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza: Thanks I think the problem is solved. I removed the Response.h and leaved only the class declaration (just curious how does that solve the issue now?)

Comment: @user2054339 well, it removes the cyclic include. You basically had a snake trying to eat its tail. Now you don't.

Comment: thanks but is it also ok that now I only declare the class and don't include it (neither in the header nor cpp file??)

Comment: @user2054339 you might have to include it in the `.cpp`, if you create any `Resoponse` instances, or call any of its methods.

Answer (score 2):

This enum has an underlying type, int in this case. So you can do the following:

```
int response = Success;
```

You can use it this way, too. See [this](http://cplus.about.com/od/learning1/ss/cppnumbers_8.htm).

Comment: This would make the code compile, but does not solve the issue.